# Problems with python IMAP and email modules and whitespace

Tags: python, email, imap, whitespace

There seems to be some inconsistency when reading the body of an email (gmail).

```
result, ems =mail.search(None,'ALL')#'UNSEEN')
if(result=='OK' and ems!=['']):
    for em in ems[0].split():
        preparse = mail.fetch(em,"(RFC822)")
        msg = email.message_from_string(preparse[1][0][1])
        for part in msg.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                to_verify = part.get_payload()
                print to_verify
                verified = verify(to_verify)
```

The problem is with to_verify. It is inconsistent with the version directly copy+pasted from my web browser. There are '\n' in unwanted places, and '\r' are added. This is causing me trouble with verifying signatures with gnupg. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you include a sample of what you expected and what you're seeing?  SMTP, for example, usually requires all lines to end in CRLF.